# Assume that Pr(A ∪ B) = 5/6 and Pr(A`|B`) = 1/3. Determine Pr(B).

Tags: probability

`Assume that Pr(A ∪ B) = 5/6 and Pr(A'|B') = 1/3. Determine Pr(B).`

Where A' is A complement and B' is B complement.

Not sure how to approach this one. Appreciate any input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**: $P(A'\mid B')\cdot P(B') = P(A'\cap B')= 1 - P(A\cup B)$. You can find $P(B')$, and then $P(B) = 1- P(B')$.